# I am not able to upload a file and what are the jar files needed for it?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I am getting blank screen when I try to uplaod the file. It goes to servlet but shows blank  browser..what are the jar files needed..and how to specify the file path.when I degug filepath is taken as `null`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class Upload extends HttpServlet {

   private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
   private int maxFileSize = 50 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
   private File file ;

   public void init( ){
      // Get the file location where it would be stored.
      filePath = 
             getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
   }
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
               HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software     Foundation\\Apache Tomcat 8.0.3\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
       // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
       out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
             String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
             // Write the file
             if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
                file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
             out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
         }
      }
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
  }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
                getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
    } 
}
```

web.xml page

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
     <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>Upload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
       </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
     <param-value>
         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat     8.0.3\webapps\data\
     </param-value> 
 </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: how is declared the servlet in web.xml? Do you have an init param named file-upload?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
     <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Upload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
       </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
     <param-value>
        C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat   8.0.3\webapps\data\
    </param-value> 
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. You should have edited your question and added this as part of the question.